# Ubuntu 12.10 will not boot!! please help

Tags: 12.10, boot

Okay ive been at this for about 6 hours now, linux has never given me problems before, im installing from an isodvd going from window7 to ubuntu12.10, the installation works fine, everything loads perfect with no problems and it asks me to restart when the installation is comeplete. After the computer shuts down and i remove the livecd as it tried to boot up i get an Error: no boot disk has been detected or the disk has failed. 
Ive tried updating grub from the livecd because it is the only way i can boot to anything atm, nothing has worked so far. Has anyone else had this problem??

Comment: check BIOS and boot order whether the HDD disk is there on the list

Comment: This is HDD error, not a OS boot error. Make sure that you can see your HDD in BIOS menu. Also Login with liveCD and check your disk health using Disk utility application.

Answer (score 1):

I've got similar issues before and every time it was something I messed up.

Check if you made good partition table, made / partition bootable and formatted everything (if you did it in manual way).

Also, check again if grub was installed correctly - that one had driven me mad many times.

Also check your MBO, maybe you have some EFI, UEFI or some other new *Windows* stuff. See if you can change some options there.

Comment: You don't have to make the / partition bootable.  The MBR boot flag only has meaning to the DOS/Windows MBR boot code; grub ignores it.